# Android circular determinate progress bar for media player

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int currentPosition = 0;
    int total = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    while (mediaPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        pbRingtonePreviewHorizontal.setProgress(currentPosition);
    }
}
```

Above is the code for update progress value, this works perfectly in horizontal progress bar.. I want same for circular progress bar.

Code for initializing progress bar is

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    System.out.println("on prepared");
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        isPlayEnabled = true;
        mediaPlayer.start();
        pbRingtonePreview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pbRingtonePreviewHorizontal.setProgress(0);
        pbRingtonePreviewHorizontal.setMax(mediaPlayer
                .getDuration());
        ivRingtonePreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
        new Thread(this).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Either make a custom circular progress bar using canvas, or use a library project. Example: https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I want circular progress bar for media player. My code is working fine with horizontal progress bar